# How to prevent one row from stacking?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I know that bootstrap defaults to stacking when viewed on mobile, which is fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to keep the State and County on the same line when on mobile.

Here is how it looks before being viewed on mobile

[image: Before mobile]

and here is how it looks when mobile

[image: Mobile]

As you can see how the State and County are on the same line before mobile, I need to have those both on the same line when in mobile.

I have tried using a pull, but not working properly for me.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ddState" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1 control-label">State</label>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
          <input id="ddState" />
        </div>

        <label for="ddCounty" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 control-label">County</label>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
          <div id="ddCounty" class="form-control"></div>
        </div>


      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End State County-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ddDepartment" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1 control-label">Department</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
          <div id="ddDepartment" class="form-control"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Department-->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ddDistrict" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1 control-label">District</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
          <div id="ddDistrict" class="form-control"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End District -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtReporter" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1 control-label">Reporter</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" id="txtReporter" class="form-control" style="max-width:100%" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Reporting Party -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtAddress" class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1 control-label">Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" id="txtAddress" class="form-control" style="max-width:100%" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Address -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div id="Cancel" class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
          <div class="form-control" style="background-color:#1D5F86; color:white; font-weight:bold">
            <center>Cancel</center>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
          <div class="form-control" style="background-color:#963146; color:white; font-weight:bold">
            <center>Submit</center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-xs-` instead of `-sm-`

https://www.codeply.com/go/ApwufRJrYd

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ddState" class="col-md-1 col-xs-2 col-md-offset-1 control-label">State</label>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4">
                    <input id="ddState">
                </div>

                <label for="ddCounty" class="col-md-1 col-xs-2 control-label">County</label>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-4">
                    <div id="ddCounty" class="form-control"></div>
                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated